# How can I remove invalid fields during Joi Schema Data Validation instead of returning an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, schema, jsonschema, joi

There is this property you provide called **stripUnknown** that removes fields that were not specified during schema creation, is there something like but which **removes invalid fields** and returns the valid ones, maybe additionally with errors. 
[Code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFZzL.png)

For example

```js
var joi = require("@hapi/joi")
let s = joi.object({
    name: joi.string(),
    username: joi.string()
})

console.log(
    s.validate({
        name: 32,
        age: 43
    }, {
        stripUnknown: true,
        convert: true
    })
)
```

Instead of it alerting the name is invalid only, it can return the value with name removed because it is invalid.

Comment: ajv gives you validation errors in a format which you can use to determine the location in your instance JSON which causes the error. You can then use this information to remove them.

Comment: Thanks @Relequestual , I ended up still using Joi, but I implemented it in a way that I provided an option of 

{abortEarly: false} during validation, which gives me the message with all paths of invalid fields which I can then extract and delete. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer per se, as there is no specific function that supports removal of certain values (at least that I know of). I do not have the ability to comment yet, thus the answer post.

You can use [Joi.custom](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.8.1#:%7E:text=any.custom(method%2C%20%5Bdescription%5D)) in order to create a custom validator.

The `custom` accepts a `callback(value,helper)` and your code could be written as:

```js
const schema = joi.object().custom((value, helper) => {
  let validatedObject = {};
  if (typeof value.name === 'string') {
    validatedObject.name = value.name;
  } 
  if (typeof value.username === 'string') {
    validatedObject.username = value.username;
  } 
  return validatedObject;
});

joi.attempt(params, schema, {stripUnknown: true});
```

This way you can return the value that you think is acceptable.
Also, you can use the `helper` object in order to retrieve various properties as the schema or the state of the current validation etc.

Hope I helped a bit